# Why is class getter transpiled to enumerable property?

Tags: ecmascript-6, getter, google-closure-compiler

getter in ES6 class is not enumerable when tested in latest chrome.

```
class Foo {
  get name() { return 'name'; }
}

// => {get: f, set: undefined, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype, 'name');
```

However, when compile this code to ES5 using closure compiler, the getter property becomes enumerable.

```
npx google-closure-compiler --js=script.js --js_output_file=out.js

var $jscomp=$jscomp||{};$jscomp.scope={};$jscomp.getGlobal=function(a){return"undefined"!=typeof window&&window===a?a:"undefined"!=typeof global&&null!=global?global:a};$jscomp.global=$jscomp.getGlobal(this);var Foo=function(){};$jscomp.global.Object.defineProperties(Foo.prototype,{name:{configurable:!0,enumerable:!0,get:function(){return"name"}}});
```

Highlight the important piece:

```
$jscomp.global.Object.defineProperties(Foo.prototype, {
  name: {
    configurable:!0,
    enumerable:!0,
    get:function(){
      return"name"
    }
  }
})
```

Is this a bug or was there any reason why closure compiler explicitly made it generate different result?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been covered in a [2015 bug report](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1158), "*Transpiled ES6 getters / setters take a lot of space (& should not be enumerable)*" but the thread ends with the issue apparently having been resolved and closed ("*I assume we can close this*").

This looks like regression of that bug (if indeed it had ever been fixed at all in the first place), and you can file a new bug to bring this to the developers' attention.